# Remove all special characters except numbers and decimal points in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string

I want to write a ruby code just to remove all special characters from a string except numbers and decimal points. I don't know the simplest way to do this.

For example- 
The string on which I want to perform the operation is test1.3eb@j$2.xyz.

Now I want only test1.3ebj2xyz as result.

I want to remove all special characters and dots (except when the dot is placed between two digits i.e when the dot is being considered as decimal point)

Please help me to sort this out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *...special characters from a string except numbers and decimal points* this definition leads us to ask you what *special characters* can be

Comment: Special characters are for example @#$%^&*()_+!><?/\{}[],:;=-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, a special character would be anything other than alphanumeric characters. If your own definition is the same then you need a regex to capture decimal numbers to save them from being removed:

```
(\d\.\d)|[^a-zA-Z\d]
```

Ruby:

```
re = /(\d\.\d)|[^a-zA-Z\d]/
str = 'test1.3eb@j$2.xyz.'
subst = '\\1'

result = str.gsub(re, subst)

puts result
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I need.